# Weird border with CSS box-shadow

Tags: css

I applied the following style to the submit button visible in this test [page](http://t1g98s1.webatu.com/button.html/) :

```
border-radius: 25px;
border: none;
background: #FE6181;
box-shadow: 0 0 0px 0.4em #f4f4f4 inset;
padding: 20px;
```

As you can see there's some awfully irregular pink border which has nothing to do here around the button. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your inset box shadow doesn't QUITE fill right out to the edges, leaving the background visible.

I'm not familiar with box shadow, but you need a shadow that is both inset and outset, but only outset by about a pixel, so it covers up the outline.

Comment: There's no such thing as a box-shadow that is both inset and outset

Comment: Then I'm unsure, but that IS the problem, the shadow not quite going up to the edge.

Answer (score 0):

The property "box-shadow" apparently render bad because of the background.

In your case using "border" may solve the problem

```
border-radius: 25px;
border: 0.4em solid #F4F4F4;
background: #FE6181;
padding: 20px;
```